# Issues getting tweets from Twitter API by date range

Tags: twitter

Good evening, StackOverflow!

I am working with twitter API to retrieve tweets from the twitter. I need to receive tweets by a time range, for example, all tweets from **@someUser** for the last week, or last 10 days... or from March to April.

I am looking at https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline documentation, and it doesn't really specify how to use the date to narrow down the list of receiving tweets. I mean, I can use **since_id** or **max_id**, but it is not really what I'm looking for.

I mean, I can receive tweets by one using max_id and since_id, check the date, and see if it falls into my time frame, and continue until I get to the edge. Anyway, it is not a good practice.

So, is there a way or maybe I missed something in the documentation?

I really would appreciate any help (just a tip would work).